# Cannot pass the pre-bios loading screen (toshiba laptop)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, bios, multi-boot, toshiba-laptop

I've just bought a Toshiba Satellite p50-A-14K. I was struggling installing ubuntu 13.10 together with windows 8.1. I couldn't get the dual boot working so at one point, what I did is to delete the boot partition (with the tool GParted) and disable the "Boot Secure" (UEFI still enabled, fast boot disabled)
...and now I am stuck with the "Toshiba Leading Innovation" screen (pre-bios screen...BIOS is never loaded)

Nothing is working. So far, I tried :

- Pressing f2, f12 (without and with holding the key Fn), 0, ESC while booting
- Booting from Toshiba Recovery Disk or from Ubuntu Live Disk
- Disassembling the laptop in order to reset the CMOS battery...well I didn't find the CMOS Battery

Please, if you have any clues how to help me and get at least Windows 8 working, I will be grateful

Comment: My Asus Zenbook did the same. Turns out the SSD (boot drive) was broken.

Comment: Have you managed to fix this issue? I'm experiencing a similar behavior on a different model.